# How to hide a portion of chart or a div in Angular?

Tags: html, css, angular, chart.js

I have a big chart I want to display in my page, the thing is this chart takes a lot of vertical space and it wouldn't be very user friendly to display the whole chart when the user visits the page page the first time.

I want to hide most of the chart and just show a speak peek , something like a text excerpt, so that the chart doesn't clutter the page, and then the user can click on it and show it in a separate page.

Now my question is how do I hide the lower part of this chart ?

Please look at the attached image for reference of what I want to achieve [image: here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say Hiding the lower part of the `div` container the chart is the easiest to do.
You can use something like the following css on your `div`:

```
.exerpt {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

You can also add some bottom shadow to hint to the users that there is more content:

```
.exerpt::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, gray, transparent);
}
```

After that you can use Angular router to navigate to a new page with the whole chart, or just an click event to change the div's height to 100%.
Here is a demo for more details: [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-pfcc4c?file=style.css)

Comment: Hi there I am happy that my answer helped you, an upvote would be very appreciated, thanks

Comment: Can't thank you enough sir!! This worked wonders for me. This was so simple and neat. I thought I'd have to use something complex in Angular. It was my first question on here, and I don't have enough karma / reputation on SO to upvote your answer even. But this community has never disappointed me

Comment: @Vishal34 ok cool, don't worry about the upvote tho :) I am glad I could help